# How to override mongoengine DictField with get_or_create?

Tags: mongoengine

I am using mongoengine's `DictField` for storing user permissions on objects:

```
permissions = mongoengine.DictField(field=mongoengine.ListField(field=mongoengine.StringField(choices=ALL_PERMISSIONS)))
```

Which in practice looks like:

```
permissions = {
    'user1id': ['VIEW'],
    'user2id': ['VIEW', 'EDIT']
}
```

So `permissions['user1id']` returns `['VIEW']` and `permissions['user3id']` raises `KeyError`.

I would like to override `DictField`'s default behavior so that `permissions['user3id']` would return `[]`. And furthermore, it would be great if I could use something like `permissions['user1id'] += 'VIEW'` and `permissions['user2id'] -= 'VIEW'`.

I've tried to override `mongengine.DictField.__getitem__` and `mongengine.DictField.__getattr__` methods, but neither of them is called.

Is this the right idea to do something like this? What am I missing?